# How does boost::asio::io_service prioritize work?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I am using `boost::asio::io_service` to manage some asynchronous TCP communication. That means I create a `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` and give the `io_service` to it. When I start the communication it goes schematically like this:

`Async Resolve -> Callback ->  Async Connect -> Callback -> Async Write -> Callback ->  Async Read`

I ommitted parts like resolve and bind. Just assume the Socket has been bound to a port and the hostname is resolved ( so connect meaning establishing the real connection to the endpoint )

Now the point is that I may start several Async Connections with the same `io_service` object. This means for example, that while in my `io_service` thread the program is about to `Async Write` some data, the main thread will call `Async Resolve` with on Socket ( but with the same `io_service` ). 
This means that my `io_service` now has some parallel work to do - what I'd like to know is how it will prioritize the work?

For example it go like this

```
Main Thread              |      io_service Thread
-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------
SocketA->Async Connect   |
//Some other Stuff       |     SocketA->Callback from Async Connect
                         |     SocketA->Async Write
SocketB->Async Connect   |      
                         |     --> ?
```

Now at this point I have to admit I am not quite sure how the `io_service` works. In the fourth line there are now two different asynchronous functions which needs to be executed.

Is `io_service` capable of doing the `Async Connect` and the `Async Write` simultaneously? If that is the case it is clear that always the callback from the function which is finished first will be called.

If the `io_service` is **not** capable of doing so, in which order will it do the work? If `SocketA Async Write` will be called first, it's callback will also be called first. Actually there will be always work until the whole operation on SocketA is finished.

**EDIT :**

According to ereOns comment I try to make my question a bit more precise:

From the view of the `io_service` thread - is the `SocketA Async Connect` call asynchronous or synchronous? From the view of my main thread it is of course asynchronous ( it just dispatches the command and then goes on ). But in the `io_service` thread will this specific `Connect` call block other operations?

In other words: Is one single `io_service` capable of Connecting to one Socket while it is reading on another?

Another example would be if I just call 2 `Async Connect` in my main function right after each other:

```
SocketA->AsyncConnect();
SocketB->AsyncConnect();
```

Let's say the Host from SocketA is a bit slow and it takes it two seconds to answer. So while SocketA is trying to connect would SocketB in the meanwhile also connect or would it have to wait until SocketA is done /timed out?

Comment: I'm not sure to completely get your question but I would say Asio will raise events as soon as possible, either the connect or the write, whichever comes first, in an unspecified order. If I may ask, why do you think the order matters ?

Comment: @ereOn I added some content to the question to make it a bit more precise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the work is done in the thread where `io_service.run()` runs.

However, the call to any `async_` method **won't** block this specific thread: it behaves exactly like if `io_service.run()` called `select()` on several events, and "returns" (calls a callback) whenever such an event is raised. That is, if you call:

```
socketA->async_connect();
socketB->async_connect();
```

`socketB` may as well connect before `socketA` and the associated callback would then be called first, still in the thread `io_service.run()` runs.

That's all the beauty of Boost Asio: it takes a very good care about polling, waiting and raising events when it is more appropriate, leaving you with the "easy" part.

Comment: Okay so this is "really" asynchronous, meaning that the `async_` methods work parallel. Which callback will be called first depends on which of the `async_` fnunctions "returns" first? Did I get this right?

Comment: Because of the new answer from "this" I need to ask again: We are speaking from the point of view from the IO_Service Thread here. I am quite aware that the async_call in the Main Thread will return immediatly. The callbacks however will be called in the io_service thread...right?!

Comment: @Toby: See it as the connect call is non-blocking in the `io_service` thread. When you call `async_connect()` on your socket, it really just pushes the call to a list which will be emptied by `io_service::run()`. This guarantees that you can call `async_connect` from any thread. However, that doesn't mean that the call be blocking. `async_connect()` will create an event, `io_service::run()` will then wait on all events he knows of and if the connection succeeds, the operating system will signal it to `run()` which will then call the adequate callback in **its own thread**.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to predict order of execution for asynchronous operations here. `async_connect` just signals to `io_service` and returns immediately. The real work gets done in `io_service` object's event processing loop (`io_service::run`), but you don't know exact specifics. It most likely uses OS-specific asynchronous IO functions.

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Maybe you should use synchronous operations. Maybe you should use thread synchronization functionality.
Maybe `io_service::run_one` will help you (it executes at most one handler).

Maybe you'll want to call `io_service::run` multiple times in separate threads, creating a thread pool. That way one long completion handler won't block all the others.

```
boost::asio::io_service service;
const size_t ASIO_THREAD_COUNT = 3;
boost::thread_group threadGroup;
for (size_t i = 0; i < ASIO_THREAD_COUNT; ++i)
        threadGroup.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run,
            &service, boost::system::error_code()));
```

Comment: This is wrong. If `io_service::run()` was just doing blocking calls in a deported thread, what would be the point of Boost Asio ? You don't need to create several threads for that, let alone a thread pool. You are building an horror to fix a problem that never existed.

Comment: Maybe I assumed too much while trying to say that one shouldn't assume too much. But it is known that handlers are called from `run`-thread. I'm not sure what you don't like about thread pool though, it's all nice and neat with Boost.Asio: quoting the [doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html): `Multiple threads may call io_service::run() to set up a pool of threads from which completion handlers may be invoked`

Comment: Nothing wrong with a thread pool when needed. But for the specific case here, it is way overkill as Boost Asio is designed to handle asynchronous events concurently.